# Swift CLI --xunit-output option not working for me

Tags: swift, swift5, swiftpm

I'm running Xcode 13.1 / Swift 5.5.1.

I have a package that has some unit tests in it; the `Package.swift` file uses `swift-tools-version:5.5`.

When I build & test my package from the CLI like this:

```
$ swift test --xunit-output results.xml
```

the tests run and pass (there's about 20 of them), but no XML output file is written to my current directory.

Am I using this command line option wrong, or does this feature just not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found out this is a known bug in Swift Package Manager:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9133

Until this issue is fixed, when using `swift test`, you must also parallelize tests with the `--parallel` option for the `--xunit-output` option to work.

Comment: Nice find. Helped me.